# Could not find service for valueType: Symbol(uiapi.RecordRepresentation)

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, browser

The below message is coming randomly on Opportunity Record page on Edge only in Lightning. It is not happening on Chrome and IE. We have a custom Lightning component on Opportunity Home page.It has Lightning Data services tags. It started only after spring 19 release.

> Could not find service for valueType:
>   Symbol(uiapi.RecordRepresentation)

Is anyone familiar of this issue? What does it actually trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, no answer here, but I'm also experiencing the same problem.  Like you it occurs only in Edge, Spring '19, and it happens with a custom component.  For me, it's on a Case.  I'm using force:recordData and also have a lightning:recordEditForm in the component.

I haven't had a chance yet to dig far enough to see if there's a pattern.  Not sure how to reproduce, sometimes it happens on load, sometimes it happens when interacting with the component. Also not sure if it has to do with recordData, recordEditForm, etc.

Just letting you know you're not alone :P

Comment: @Stephen  I have raised a case with Salesforce, they have confirmed it as their internal issue. They have fixed it.

Comment: I have a user with this same issue. He said it is occurring on Chrome too.